# Adding jQuery Slider into Magento Theme

Tags: conflict

I'm trying to add a jQuery slider into my Magento theme. The slider is working perfectly in HTML of the theme I have. But I'm having problem integrating it into Magento theme, probably due to jQuery conflict with Magento's prototype js. This is what I've done so far:

I've added jquery file through jquery library direct link, and then added noConflict function, as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

I've also added the necessary jQuery file in local.xml file, and when the page is rendered it is correctly shown in page source, as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/menstyle3/skin/frontend/webdezynertheme/default/js/plugins.js"></script>
```

The code in the plugins.js file starts something like this, and goes on:

```
    if (!(window.console && console.log)) {
    (function() {
        var noop = function() {};
        var methods = ['assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error', 'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log', 'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'markTimeline', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd', 'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'];
        var length = methods.length;
        var console = window.console = {};
        while (length--) {
            console[methods[length]] = noop;
        }
    }());
}

    ;(function($){
            $.fn.pajinate = function(options){
```

I've tried but I was unable to make it work. Should I just replace the starting '$' with 'jQuery' or should I replace every instance of '$'? Is that all I should try, or do I have to do something else as well?

P.S: Firefox->Inspect Element->Console is not showing any JS errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the plugin is using a closure to namespace the dollar variable. If you scroll down to match up the brackets, does it by any change look like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.pajinate = function(options){
    // lots of code here
}($));
```

If it does, then you should just be able to change it to be:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.pajinate = function(options){
    // lots of code here
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Guess what...it is already in this form:
`(function($) {
    $.fn.pajinate = function(options){
    // lots of code here
}(jQuery));`
But still isn't working...

Comment: adding this above jQuery code:
`var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); `
and then replacing the normal "$" with a new shorthand worked!
Thanks anyway!